# Delete 2d Vector of Object Pointers C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, vector, memory-leaks

I have been searching for 2 hours now and trying to figure out how to do this one very simple task.

```
vector<vector<MappedGraphItem*>> odd_vertex_matrix;
```

When I add items to the vector, it looks like this:

```
    for (auto i : odd_vertices) {
        oci = 0;
        for (auto j : odd_vertices) {
            odd_vertex_matrix[ori][oci] = new MappedGraphItem(i, j, adjacentMatrix[i][j]);
            odd_vertex_matrix[oci][ori] = new MappedGraphItem(j, i, adjacentMatrix[j][i]);
            oci++;
        }
        ori++;
}
```

For those who are curious, here is what the MappedGraphItem class looks like

```
    #include "common.h"

class MappedGraphItem {
public:

    MappedGraphItem(int ari, int aci, float w) :
        adj_row_index(ari),
        adj_col_index(aci),
        weight(w) {}

    MappedGraphItem() :
        adj_row_index(0),
        adj_col_index(0),
        weight(0) {}

    ~MappedGraphItem() {}
    int adj_row_index;
    int adj_col_index;
    float weight;
};
```

When I go to delete the 2d vector, I use this:

```
for (auto i = odd_vertex_matrix.begin(); i != odd_vertex_matrix.end(); ++i)
    for (auto j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j)
        delete *j;
```

And yet, I am still getting memory leaks with this. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I would really not use smart pointers. I don't know them, and I feel like they are overkill for what I am trying to do here. There must be a simply way.

-Thanks!

Comment: What are `ori` and `odd_vertices`? Better post an MCVE. Also, do you really need to store pointers?

Comment: Does the array ever change between when it's first populated and when you delete it? Even if your code to delete it is fine, there will be leaks if the array is changing. Absolutely recommend smart pointer for this case.

Comment: @juanchopanza `ori` and `oci` are simply `int` counters that start at 0. `adjacentMatrix` is just a 2d array of floats. I dont see how knowing what those are is relevant to my question. I just want to know what syntax to use to delete the vector

Comment: @JamesDean You can't see why it is relevant? Because depending on the values of the indices you may be leaking memory like crazy?

Answer (score 1):

In your allocation routine, you allocate twice the number of required `MappedGraphicsItem`.
If you have `N` odd vertices, then you will allocate `2*N*N` elements.
The deletion routine is correct though.

**Rationale:**

The double `for` loop at the beginning is the cartesian product of `odd_vertices` with itself.
Thus, it touches each vertex once in each `for` loop, hence the `N^2` inner loops.
However, you allocate **2 items** each time you touch an element.

You can see it by forgetting the `auto`syntax and writing the loop indices explicitly:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < odd_vertices.size(); ++i) {
    oci = 0;
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < odd_vertices.size(); ++j) {
        odd_vertex_matrix[ori][oci] = new MappedGraphItem(odd_vertices[i], odd_vertices[j], adjacentMatrix[i][j]);
        odd_vertex_matrix[oci][ori] = new MappedGraphItem(odd_vertices[j], odd_vertices[i], adjacentMatrix[j][i]);
        oci++;
    }
    ori++;
}
```

If you want to keep your code *as is*, then you need to add a test to check whether you have already allocated the subdiagonal element, or modify the inner loop by creating a new list:

```
for (auto i : odd_vertices) {
  oci = 0;
  for (auto j: std::vector<...>(i, odd_vertices.end())) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* need to use pointers then use this instead:

`vector<vector<std::unique_ptr<MappedGraphItem>>> odd_vertex_matrix;`

The `vector` will then own the allocated memory: it will be freed when the `vector` destructs.

`std::unique_ptr` is new to C++11 and is not a *smart* pointer in the traditional sense.

Comment: what's the benefit over `vector<vector<MappedGraphItem>>`?

Comment: @Bathsheba
The `MappedGraphItem` class is shown above in my code. It consists of only 3 ints.

Comment: @juanchopanza
It is a bit of a contrived exercise. This is mostly just for practice. I want to learn how this is done.